# What we install in Virtualbox using Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

I just started learning [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and succeeded in using it. I went through this [vagrantbox.es](http://www.vagrantbox.es/) where we "download" the "templates".

I have some doubts and would be great if anyone can explain me:

1) `Vagrant` --> My understanding is t hat it helps in automating installing the Virtual machines in Virtualization software like Virtualbox. Is this correct?

2) Now, as per the instructions that I followed in one of the video tutorials, we need to 'download' the VM, from [this](http://www.vagrantbox.es/)  link.

My doubt is what are we downloading from the link in point #2? Using Vagrant, are we downloading a VM (and which gets installed into Virtualbox, for example?). Can't we use any .iso image and let vagrant install it? I am bit confused here.

Can anyone who has used vagrant explain what exactly are we downloading?

Comment: Yes, you're downloading a VM which somebody else has already created for you so you don't have to worry about setting up a new installation of Linux or whatever you're trying to set up. There are rather elaborate "template VMs" you can download, including a full setup of Apache + PHP or whatever. You can still set up your own VMs from scratch of course if you prefer that.

Comment: @deceze: Thanks for your reply, appreciate a lot. Are these VM's to be trusted, the way we trust the .iso image when we download, for example, from Ubuntu? Would a Big company trust these images? And finally, are these images "full" OS plus the tools (e.g. tomcat, php as you described)?

Comment: A very valid concern. There's no answer. *You* investigate where those images come from and whether you trust the source. Since a complete VM is a very complex system which can literally do anything (like send all its memory contents off to some 3rd party without you noticing), trust concerns are very real. And again, yes, they're a full VM. How exactly they're set up depends on who set them up.

Answer (score 1):

> 2) Now, as per the instructions that I followed in one of the video tutorials, we need to 'download' the VM, from this link.

Must be a bit dated tutorials, even though it is still a good reference, nowadays people will download boxes from https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search. The platform is officially supported by hashicorp but everyone can upload boxes into the platform, and you can directly reference boxes from atlas such as [`ubuntu/trusty64`](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64) in your vagrantfile and vagrant will know how to download the box and install it for you so it saves you some steps.

> My doubt is what are we downloading from the link in point #2? Using Vagrant, are we downloading a VM (and which gets installed into Virtualbox, for example?). Can't we use any .iso image and let vagrant install it? I am bit confused here.

There are some 'official' box supported by hashicorp. Some organization like laravel pushes their own official boxes (like laravel/homestead and they support virtual box and vmware provider). It will be up to you to review the box you reference and make sure about its source.

you can create your own box from the OS iso using tool such as [packer](https://www.packer.io/) you will find plenty of available packer templates on github to create boxes for different OS flavors

> And finally, are these images "full" OS plus the tools (e.g. tomcat, php as you described)

This will depend - in the case of Laravel they would provide a box with OS + the stack but generally the boxes are minimal (and you want to keep it this way). You will [provision](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/) this using a tool of your choice (shell, ansible, puppet ...)